# Add transition effect on div using CSS

Tags: html, css, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have following code on HTML:

```
<div class="container">
   <div class="row document__box">
      <div class="col-2" style="padding-left:10px;">
         <img src="">         
      </div>
      <div class="col-10">
         <span class="document__anchor">Lorem Ipsum this is a title</span>
         
      </div>
      <div id="first" >
         <span @click="activate(i)" class="document__open_doc">
            <b-icon icon="chevron-double-left" variant="white"></b-icon>
         </span>
         <div id="" v-bind:class="{ active : active_el === i }" class="document__closed_div">
            <span @click="activate(i)" class="document__close_doc">
               <b-icon icon="chevron-double-right" variant="white"></b-icon>
            </span>
            <span class="pr-2 pl-2 document__action_icon">
               Lorem Ipsum this is a excerpt
            </span>          

         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

On the click of first `activate()` of a class `document__open_doc`, div with the class `document__closed_div` should slide to the left and on the click of second `activate()`, `document__closed_div` should slide to the right.

I have written following css:

```
.document__closed_div.active,
.document__closed_div{
  transition: 1s;
}
.document__closed_div.active{
  transform: translate(0%, 0);
}
.document__closed_div{
  transform: translate(-100%, 0);
}
```

but it is not working. I am doing it correctly?

The image is for reference [image]

Answer (score 1):

The `transition` property should only be applied to the default state, and it should include either which parameter you want to transition (in your case `transform`) or instead the word "all", so in your case that CSS rule would be

```
.document__closed_div {
  transition: all 1s;
}
```

Comment: Can you please write the whole css rule I have written in my question? Because I update my `.document__closed_div` css with yours, I am still not getting the result.